# Has anyone been able to run Assassin's Creed 1 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, assassins-creed

Please note that I'm talking about Assassin's Creed 1 and not 2. I know that 2 supports Windows 7. It's part 1 that I'm concerned about.

I had installed that game sometime a while back but had been unable to run it on Windows 7. On running it, I get a black screen. I don't know whether thats a specific problem or everyone is having it.

So, is there anyone who has been able to run it successfully on Windows 7 **with an on-board graphics card?** And if yes, what steps specifically did you follow?

**Edit:** I tried the test at http://www.systemrequirementslab.com and it passed everything except the graphics card name test - shows up as unrecognized. However, every component of the graphics card passed the test.

**2nd Edit:** You can also try out Swiftshader and 3d Analyze in case you are trying to install. If it works out, please let me know the settings.

Comment: I'm still looking for answers..

Comment: This is getting new answers, although it's a class of question we have since [decided to decline to answer.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/can-i-ask-if-a-specific-game-will-run-on-a-specific-computer-system)  Therefore, I'm closing this to prevent further answers.  My apologies for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have Windows 7 and am playing Assassin's Creed 1 right now with no problems whatsoever.  I don't have a very powerful machine, with a 2.9 GHz Core 2 Duo Processor with 1 GB RAM and an onboard graphics card Intel G41 Express Chipset, so it does run, although only on the lower end of graphics and detail settings, but well and fast. The problem with you is most likely in the copy of the game you have, perhaps with some missing files. If not that, then it's surely a problem with the graphics card. Not that it's not fast enough, but because it's not compatible with the processor you have.

Comment: Since I have onboard graphics I don't think a scenario is possible that it is not compatible with the processor that I have. However, if the game runs on your on board graphics and not on mine then clearly it does not support the one I have. I think this answers my question then. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I downloaded and bought AC1 from Direct Drive and had no problems with installation or playing the game with Windows 7. I do not have integrated graphics card however.

Comment: Yeah I think my problem is probably due to the on-board graphics. But the strange thing is that I'm able to play games like call of duty 4 and Monkey Island series with no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I didn´t have any problems on my sony vaio laptop running Assasins Creed. Laptop is a FNZ340

Comment: Could you tell me your your graphics card device? (if you go to device manager and check under display adapters, what do you see listed)?

Answer (score 1):

I have Intel G41 express chipset graphics card on board. I'm able to run Assassins creed 1 with shadows disabled and resolution set to 800*600 and it runs at good FPS(30-35)